# How to get the ChoiceField value using javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-channels

First of all sorry for my bad english i am french !

So i have a little problem. I use the django built-in class ChoiceField in my form :

```
class LogForm(forms.Form):
    FormData = (('1', 'Code',), ('2', 'Normal',), ('3', 'Hexa',))
    choixFormData = forms.ChoiceField(label=' Forme des donnees ', choices=FormData)
    liaison = (('1', 'RS232_1_Port1',), ('2', 'RS232_1_Port2',), ('3', 'RS232_1_Port3',), ('4', 'RS232_1_Port4',),
               ('5', 'RS422_1_Port1',), ('6', 'RS422_1_Port2',), ('7', 'RS422_1_Port3',), ('8', 'RS422_1_Port4',),
               ('9', 'RS422_2_Port1',), ('10', 'RS422_2_Port2',), ('11', 'RS422_2_Port3',), ('12', 'RS422_2_Port4',),
               ('13', 'VoieNumAna',), ('14', 'CAN1',), ('15', '1553',))
    choixLiaison = forms.ChoiceField(label='Liaison', choices=liaison)
    Data = forms.CharField(required=False, label=' Data ', max_length=100, widget=forms.Textarea)
```

And i also use the Django Channels in order to implement websockets in my app.

The thing is, i want to be able to render the form thanks to the view ( this is working fine ) and then i want to get the value of the selected choice ( once the the form is rendered ) using javascript.

I tried this :

```
document.querySelector('#id_Start').onclick = function(e) {
    const messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#id_choixLiaison');
    const message = messageInputDom.value;
    chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
        'message': message
    }));
    messageInputDom.value = '';
}
```

I am very new to javascript and i dont understand the reason why this is not working.
I want to be able to get the value of the selected choice field in a string.

Do not hesitate to tell me if the question is badly asked or if you need more details.

Thank you !

Comment: Do basic debugging: `console.log(messageInputDom);` and `console.log(message);` what do you see?

Comment: I just tried it and it does nothing.

Comment: Ok, so what does the final HTML look like? Press Ctrl+U in the browser to see it. Do you have `<select id="id_choixLiaison">` in there?

Comment: Yes the id i'm using is the right one.

Comment: Well, your code works in theory: https://jsfiddle.net/Le9tn61z/ We cannot debug this until we see your actual code, ideally in the form of a [mre].